# C# Creating chat rooms with multi client-server Sockets

Tags: c#, sockets, client-server, chatroom

Good afternoon, i've been trying to make a system kinda like skype in terms of convo groups, being able to enter a group and chatting with others that were online only within that group, issue is i dont know how i could separate this chat room into several ones and making them independent from each other with just one server

Overall, im trying to have multi chat rooms with one server while being able to save one's conversation chat log and be able to read it back

The current code i have works only as 1 general chat room
Server Side:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Socket newSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Ip);
        IPEndPoint endPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 6000);
        newSocket.Bind(endPoint);
        newSocket.Listen(10);
        Console.Write("Waiting...\n");
        while (true)
        {

            Socket auxSocket = newSocket.Accept();
            ThreadLab a = new ThreadLab(auxSocket);
            Thread novaThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(a.Connect));
            novaThread.Start();

        }
    }
```

The ThreadLab Class:

```
private Socket socket;
        static int nmrUsers = 0;
        static int indice;
        static Socket[] listaSockets = new Socket[10];
        static ArrayList listaUtilizadores = new ArrayList();

        public ThreadLab(Socket s)
        {
            socket = s;
            listaSockets[indice++] = s;
        }

        public void Connect()
        {
            IPEndPoint aux = (IPEndPoint)socket.RemoteEndPoint;
            Console.Write("Client " + aux.Address.ToString() + " connected\n");
        }
```

And the client side that will have the reader and writer:

```
private static Socket client = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Ip);
        private static ThreadStart tSReader;
        private static ThreadStart tSWriter;
        private static Thread tReader;
        private static Thread tWriter;
        private static string nome;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            IPEndPoint clientEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 6000);
            tSReader = new ThreadStart(reader);
            tSWriter = new ThreadStart(writer);
            tReader = new Thread(tSReader);
            tWriter = new Thread(tSWriter);

            try
            {
                client.Connect(clientEndPoint);
            }
            catch (SocketException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
                Console.ReadLine();
                return;
            }
            tReader.Start();
            tWriter.Start();
        }
        public static void writer()
        {
            string str;

            byte[] data = new byte[1024];

            nome = Console.ReadLine();
            data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(nome);
            client.Send(data, data.Length, SocketFlags.None);

            do
            {
                str = Console.ReadLine();
                data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(str);
                client.Send(data, data.Length, SocketFlags.None);

            } while (str != "exit");

            client.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
            tReader.Abort();
            client.Close();
        }

        public static void reader()
        {
            byte[] data = new byte[1024];
            int recv;
            while (true)
            {
                try
                {
                    recv = client.Receive(data);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Erro: " + e.Message);
                    Console.ReadLine();
                    break;
                }

                Console.WriteLine("\n" + Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, recv));

            }
        }
    }
```

Someone can help me?